# Grammar or txt into a string to parse later in C#

Tags: c#

is there anyway to load a grammar like this

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Animals")))));
```

or like this

```
string contents = (File.ReadAllText(@"Default Animals.txt"));
```

into a string so I can then check with a IF statement if a certain word is in that text?

Example*

```
 if(speech.Contains(contents)) 
{
  kevin.speak("It worked");
} else {
  kevin.speak("It didnt work");
}
 break;
```

Problem is, It will only read the "Default Animals text if there is only one word in it...
like
    dog
but if the .txt looks like this

```
dog
cat
fish
```

It will not read it. I want it to check if the .txt contains that word and if it does then give me the correct response.

Comment: So `contents` can contain multiple words. What about`speech` - what might it be?

Comment: I would just say for instance, " I like dogs" and my IF statment is looking to see if my speech contains contents, and contents = the txt file of animals and dogs is in there

Comment: Have you tried File.ReadAllLines() instead? If you use that method, you get an array of all lines in the text file. File.ReadAllText will return a single string with all of the text in the file.

Comment: Why do you need Grammer to just check if a string contains words? What is kevin? Why is your example so long?

Comment: What if you say 'cat' but your text file contains 'scatter'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to test if the speech string contains any of the animals defined in the text file.

```
        string speech = "i want a tiger";

        var allAnimals = File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Animals.txt");
        if (allAnimals.Any(x => speech.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1))
        {
            kevin.speak("It worked");
        }
        else
        {
            kevin.speak("It didnt work");
        }
```

Comment: And what of "cat" -> "A catalyst is a substance which causes the process of catalysis" :)

Comment: Then you can use regex for testing (`instead of indexof != -1`): `Regex.IsMatch(speech, string.Format(@"(?:\s|^){0}(?:\s|$)", x), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the method you are looking for is

```
File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile)
```

That will read all of the file contents into a variable.

Comment: How do I  put that into a string? Everytime I use File.ReadAllLines I get red lines underneath saying cannot convert type String[] to string

Comment: That is because you are declaring the type of your variable `contents` as a string, yet ReadAllLines() returns a string array. Just declare it as `string[] contents`.

Comment: Im not getting this....var contents = (File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Animals.txt"));
           
            
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            switch (speech)
            {

                #region IF Statments

                default:

                    if (speech.ToLower().Contains(contents))
                    { 
                    
                        
                    
                    
                    } syas the best overload method has invaldi arguments

Comment: Your issue is still the same. `contents`, although you've declared it as `var` is an array of `string`s.